# Changing image in adjacent ImageButtons (Android)

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

So I'm trying to make a little game for Android. It's about turning lights on and off. I have 25 ImageButtons and, when I press one, I need the ones that are adjacent (up, left, down, right) to change too.
The thing is that I can't find a way to get/identify this buttons.
I tried using "view.getX()" and "view.getY()" but don't know how to implement them the right way (if there is one).
Here's the code I use to change ONE button:

```
    public void change(View view)
{
    String state = view.getTag().toString();
    if (state.equals("on"))
    {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lightOff));
        view.setTag("off");
        lightsOn -= 1;
        txtNumLights.setText(String.valueOf(lightsOn));
    }
    if (state.equals("off")) {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lightOn));
        view.setTag("on");
        lightsOn += 1;
        txtNumLights.setText(String.valueOf(lightsOn));
    }
}
```

I use the tags to know if it's On or Off and set a txtView with the number of ON lights.
But, to the point, how do I get the ones adjacent to this one?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend a 2d array to sort all your button instances into, then using that grid to do what you want... easier than directly finding them on the display.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the buttons on a bidimensional array.

When you click on one button, you set the tag and the background on the buttons you are interested on.

Pseudocode:

```
If (button_matrix[row][column] is clicked) then
    Set_tag_background (button_matrix[row-1][column])
    Set_tag_background (button_matrix[row+1][column])
    Set_tag_background (button_matrix[row][column-1])
    Set_tag_background (button_matrix[row][column+1])
    Set_tag_background (button_matrix[row][column])
    ...
```

On the implementation you should take care about not generating ArrayOutOfBoundsException...